# Loop through each child element and compare its text in java

Tags: java, android

I am trying to build an android app that gets some questions from a database and its possible answers (the answers are created dynamically as UI buttons). What I have managed so far is that once the user clicks on an answer, if the answer is right the button's colour becomes green, and if the answer is wrong the colour becomes red. What I want to achieve is in case the answer was wrong, change the button's colour to red and find the button with the correct answer and change it's colour to green. I am currently trying to do this by looping through every child element of the clicked button's parent, and comparing its text with the right answer given from the database. This is what my code looks like:

```js
final TableRow textRow = new TableRow(this);
textRow.addView(questionText, rowParamsQuestions);

layout.addView(textRow, layoutParams);

for(final String option : currentQuestion.getOptions())
                {
                    final Button button = new Button(this);
                    button.setText(option);
                    button.setTextSize(16);
                    button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_shape);
                    button.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Button clicked = (Button) v;

                            if (!answeredQuestions.containsKey(currentQuestion)) {
                                answeredQuestions.put(currentQuestion, clicked.getText().toString());
                                if (clicked.getText().equals(currentQuestion.getAnswer())) {
                                    clicked.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.right_answer);
                                } else {
                                    clicked.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wrong_answer);
                                    for (int i = 0; i < textRow.getChildCount(); i++) {
                                        View child = textRow.getChildAt(i);
                                       if (child instanceof Button) {
                                            if (((Button) child).getText().equals(currentQuestion.getAnswer())) {
                                                child.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.right_answer);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: What's the question? Are you asking if there is a better way?

Comment: No, what I have right now doesn't work. The wrong answer turns red, but after that whatever is inside the for (int i = 0; i < textRow.getChildCount(); i++) loop doesn't get executed.

Comment: You haven't provided sufficient details to narrow down the issue. Edit your question and provide more information. Does`textRow.getChildCount()` return a value greater than 0? Is `child` actually an `instanceof` `Button`? How are you sure that the `for` loop doesn't get executed? Could it be possible that you have white spaces on one side of the equation? Try changing your if condition in the `for` loop to `if (((Button) child).getText().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(currentQuestion.getAnswer().trim()))`

Comment: I was adding every button to a TableRow so the statement 'instanceof Button' was not returning anything. I removed the lines were I was adding my buttons to tableRows and now it works! Thanks!

Comment: You might as well add that as an answer so that other users can find it useful as well and they don't spend time answering it.